# flex mvc architecture

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller

hii.
im just beginer in flex development. I wish to do projects in mvc pattern. Have any tutorial or web sites to study flex using mvc. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into Mate and Swiz framework. They are becoming popular and they have better structure and practices. I am not a supporter of Cairngrom, though i have used them in some of my projects.

http://mate.asfusion.com/

http://swizframework.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can research some of the Flex Fameworks out there.  Cairngorm is the most popular as it has been around the longest.  Also look into PureMIVC and Mate.  Robotlegs appears to the be newest favorite of the community.

I'm sure all frameworks have documentation and/or sample apps.  Google the framework name to find ot more info.

Comment: Thanks for valueable sugetions.